# Animating CALayer shadow simultaneously as UITableviewCell height animates

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-animation, calayer

I have a UITableView that I am attempting to expand and collapse using its `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` methods and have a drop shadow displayed as that's happening. In my custom UITableViewCell, I have a layer which I create a shadow for in `layoutSubviews`:

```
self.shadowLayer.shadowColor = self.shadowColor.CGColor;
self.shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(self.shadowOffsetWidth, self.shadowOffsetHeight);
self.shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = self.shadowOpacity;
self.shadowLayer.masksToBounds = NO;
self.shadowLayer.frame = self.layer.bounds;
// this is extremely important for performance when drawing shadows
UIBezierPath *shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.shadowLayer.frame cornerRadius:self.cornerRadius];
self.shadowLayer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath;
```

I add this layer to the UITableViewCell in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.shadowLayer = [CALayer layer];
self.shadowLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
[self.layer insertSublayer:self.shadowLayer below:self.contentView.layer];
```

As I understand it, when I call `beginUpdates`, an implicit `CALayerTransaction` is made for the current run loop if none exists. Additionally, `layoutSubviews` also gets called. The problem here is that the resulting shadow is drawn immediately based on the new size of the UITableViewCell. I really need to shadow to continue to cast in the expected way as the actual layer is animating.

Since my created layer is not a backing CALayer it animates without explicitly specifying a CATransaction, which is expected. But, as I understand it, I really need some way to grab hold of `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates` CATransaction and perform the animation in that. How do I do that, if at all?

Answer (score 24):

So I guess you have something like this:

[image: bad animation]

(I turned on “Debug > Slow Animations” in the simulator.) And you don't like the way the shadow jumps to its new size. You want this instead:

[image: good animation]

You can find my test project [in this github repository](https://github.com/mayoff/animate-CALayer-shadowPath).

See [@horseshoe7's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47472010/77567) for a Swift translation.

It is tricky but not impossible to pick up the animation parameters and add an animation in the table view's animation block. The trickiest part is that you need to update the `shadowPath` in the `layoutSubviews` method of the shadowed view itself, or of the shadowed view's immediate superview. In my demo video, that means that the `shadowPath` needs to be updated by the `layoutSubviews` method of the green box view or the green box's immediate superview.

I chose to create a `ShadowingView` class whose only job is to draw and animate the shadow of one of its subviews. Here's the interface:

```
@interface ShadowingView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *shadowedView;

@end
```

To use `ShadowingView`, I added it to my cell view in my storyboard. Actually it's nested inside a stack view inside the cell. Then I added the green box as a subview of the `ShadowingView` and connected the `shadowedView` outlet to the green box.

The `ShadowingView` implementation has three parts. One is its `layoutSubviews` method, which sets up the layer shadow properties on its own layer to draw a shadow around its `shadowedView` subview:

```
@implementation ShadowingView

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CALayer *layer = self.layer;
    layer.backgroundColor = nil;

    CALayer *shadowedLayer = self.shadowedView.layer;
    if (shadowedLayer == nil) {
        layer.shadowColor = nil;
        return;
    }

    NSAssert(shadowedLayer.superlayer == layer, @"shadowedView must be my direct subview");

    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor.CGColor;
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
    layer.shadowRadius = 3;
    layer.masksToBounds = NO;

    CGFloat radius = shadowedLayer.cornerRadius;
    layer.shadowPath = CGPathCreateWithRoundedRect(shadowedLayer.frame, radius, radius, nil);
}
```

When this method is run inside an animation block (as is the case when the table view animates a change in the size of a cell), and the method sets `shadowPath`, Core Animation looks for an “action” to run after updating `shadowPath`. One of the ways it looks is by sending `actionForLayer:forKey:` to the layer's delegate, and the delegate is the `ShadowingView`. So we override `actionForLayer:forKey:` to provide an action if possible and appropriate. If we can't, we just call `super`.

It is important to understand that Core Animation asks for the action from inside the `shadowPath` setter, **before** actually changing the value of `shadowPath`.

To provide the action, we make sure the key is `@"shadowPath"`, that there is an existing value for `shadowPath`, and that there is already an animation on the layer for `bounds.size`. Why do we look for an existing `bounds.size` animation? Because that existing animation has the duration and timing function we should use to animate `shadowPath`. If everything is in order, we grab the existing `shadowPath`, make a copy of the animation, store them in an action, and return the action:

```
- (id<CAAction>)actionForLayer:(CALayer *)layer forKey:(NSString *)event {
    if (![event isEqualToString:@"shadowPath"]) { return [super actionForLayer:layer forKey:event]; }

    CGPathRef priorPath = layer.shadowPath;
    if (priorPath == NULL) { return [super actionForLayer:layer forKey:event]; }

    CAAnimation *sizeAnimation = [layer animationForKey:@"bounds.size"];
    if (![sizeAnimation isKindOfClass:[CABasicAnimation class]]) { return [super actionForLayer:layer forKey:event]; }

    CABasicAnimation *animation = [sizeAnimation copy];
    animation.keyPath = @"shadowPath";
    ShadowingViewAction *action = [[ShadowingViewAction alloc] init];
    action.priorPath = priorPath;
    action.pendingAnimation = animation;
    return action;
}

@end
```

What does the action look like? Here's the interface:

```
@interface ShadowingViewAction : NSObject <CAAction>
@property (nonatomic, strong) CABasicAnimation *pendingAnimation;
@property (nonatomic) CGPathRef priorPath;
@end
```

The implementation requires a `runActionForKey:object:arguments:` method. In this method, we update the animation that we created in `actionForLayer:forKey:` using the saved-away old `shadowPath` and the new `shadowPath`, and then we add the animation to the layer.

We also need to manage the retain count of the saved path, because ARC doesn't manage `CGPath` objects.

```
@implementation ShadowingViewAction

- (void)runActionForKey:(NSString *)event object:(id)anObject arguments:(NSDictionary *)dict {
    if (![anObject isKindOfClass:[CALayer class]] || _pendingAnimation == nil) { return; }
    CALayer *layer = anObject;
    _pendingAnimation.fromValue = (__bridge id)_priorPath;
    _pendingAnimation.toValue = (__bridge id)layer.shadowPath;
    [layer addAnimation:_pendingAnimation forKey:@"shadowPath"];
}

- (void)setPriorPath:(CGPathRef)priorPath {
    CGPathRetain(priorPath);
    CGPathRelease(_priorPath);
    _priorPath = priorPath;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    CGPathRelease(_priorPath);
}

@end
```

Comment: Rob, this is terrific!  This was exactly the solution I was looking for.  I translated it to Swift and will post it here too.

Comment: You get an upvote, @horseshoe7 gets an upvote. This both solved my problem and taught me something new about CoreAnimation.

Comment: Super Amazing... Thanks to both.. Rob for his amazing work.. HorseShoe7 for Swift translation!

Comment: What an amazing answer! just learned the CAAction from this answer! Thanks Rob!

Answer (score 9):

This is Rob Mayoff's answer written in Swift.  Could save someone some time.

Please don't upvote this.  Upvote Rob Mayoff's solution.  It is awesome, and correct. (Note from mayoff: why not upvote both? )

```
import UIKit

class AnimatingShadowView: UIView {

    struct DropShadowParameters {
        var shadowOpacity: Float = 0
        var shadowColor: UIColor? = .black
        var shadowRadius: CGFloat = 0
        var shadowOffset: CGSize = .zero
        
        static let defaultParameters = DropShadowParameters(shadowOpacity: 0.15,
                                                            shadowColor: .black,
                                                            shadowRadius: 5,
                                                            shadowOffset: CGSize(width: 0, height: 1))
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!  // no sense in have a shadowView without content!
    
    var shadowParameters: DropShadowParameters = DropShadowParameters.defaultParameters
    
    private func apply(dropShadow: DropShadowParameters) {
        let layer = self.layer
        layer.shadowColor = dropShadow.shadowColor?.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = dropShadow.shadowOffset
        layer.shadowOpacity = dropShadow.shadowOpacity
        layer.shadowRadius = dropShadow.shadowRadius
        layer.masksToBounds = false
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let layer = self.layer
        layer.backgroundColor = nil
        
        let contentLayer = self.contentView.layer
        assert(contentLayer.superlayer == layer, "contentView must be a direct subview of AnimatingShadowView!")
        
        self.apply(dropShadow: self.shadowParameters)
        
        let radius = contentLayer.cornerRadius
        layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: contentLayer.frame, cornerRadius: radius).cgPath
    }
    
    override func action(for layer: CALayer, forKey event: String) -> CAAction? {
        guard event == "shadowPath" else {
            return super.action(for: layer, forKey: event)
        }
        
        guard let priorPath = layer.shadowPath else {
            return super.action(for: layer, forKey: event)
        }
        
        guard let sizeAnimation = layer.animation(forKey: "bounds.size") as? CABasicAnimation else {
            return super.action(for: layer, forKey: event)
        }
        
        let animation = sizeAnimation.copy() as! CABasicAnimation
        animation.keyPath = "shadowPath"
        let action = ShadowingViewAction()
        action.priorPath = priorPath
        action.pendingAnimation = animation
        return action
    }
}


private class ShadowingViewAction: NSObject, CAAction {
    var pendingAnimation: CABasicAnimation? = nil
    var priorPath: CGPath? = nil
    
    // CAAction Protocol
    func run(forKey event: String, object anObject: Any, arguments dict: [AnyHashable : Any]?) {
        guard let layer = anObject as? CALayer, let animation = self.pendingAnimation else {
            return
        }
        
        animation.fromValue = self.priorPath
        animation.toValue = layer.shadowPath
        layer.add(animation, forKey: "shadowPath")
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of asking people to `Please don't upvote this. Upvote Rob Mayoff's solution.` you could edit his answer and add the swift code to it!  (That would have saved me about 30 minutes of converting it to swift myself before I saw your comment :) )  - regardless, I've up-voted your answer and his.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you're manually setting your `shadowPath`, here's a solution inspired by the others here that accomplishes the same thing using less code.

Note that I'm intentionally constructing my own `CABasicAnimation` rather than copying the `bounds.size` animation exactly, as in my own tests I found that toggling the copied animation while it was still in progress could cause the animation to snap to it's `toValue`, rather than transitioning smoothly from its current value.

```swift
class ViewWithAutosizedShadowPath: UIView {
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        let oldShadowPath = layer.shadowPath
        let newShadowPath = CGPath(rect: bounds, transform: nil)
        
        if let boundsAnimation = layer.animation(forKey: "bounds.size") as? CABasicAnimation {
            let shadowPathAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "shadowPath")

            shadowPathAnimation.duration = boundsAnimation.duration
            shadowPathAnimation.timingFunction = boundsAnimation.timingFunction

            shadowPathAnimation.fromValue = oldShadowPath
            shadowPathAnimation.toValue = newShadowPath
            
            layer.add(shadowPathAnimation, forKey: "shadowPath")
        }
        
        layer.shadowPath = newShadowPath
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Would it make sense to remove the current shadowPath animation before adding the modified one? For example: `layer.removeAnimation(forKey: "shadowPath"); layer.add(..)`

Comment: IIRC adding a new animation for the same key replaces the old automatically

Comment: You are correct: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410848-addanimation

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView` is likely not creating a `CATransaction`, or if it is, it's waiting until after you end the updates. My understanding is that table views just coalesce all changes between those functions and then creates the animations as necessary. You don't have a way to get a handle on the actual animation parameters it's committing, because we don't know when that actually happens. The same thing happens when you animate a content offset change in `UIScrollView`: the system provides no context about the animation itself, which is frustrating. There is also no way to query the system for current `CATransaction`s.

Probably the best you can do is inspect the animation that `UITableView` is creating and just mimic the same timing parameters in your own animation. Swizzling `add(_:forKey:)` on `CALayer` can allow you to inspect all animations being added. You certainly don't want to actually ship with this, but I often use this technique in debugging to figure out what animations are being added and what their properties are.

I suspect that you're going to have to commit your own shadow layer animations in `tableView(_:willDisplayCell:for:row:)` for the appropriate cells.